# Weblogic application port for web apps

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic9.x

I have deployed a java web application jar file on weblogic 10.3.
But I'm unsure how to access the application in browser.
I have the path to my web app as "/testapp/home.do"
Can someone tell me what port is used by weblogic apps.
Where can I check the port number info,which file?

When deployed on tomcat, i use `"localhost:8080/testapp/home.do"`
I'm looking for something similar for weblogic

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Weblogic Administration Console i.e.

Deployments => Click on theApp => Testing Tab => Default URL in the table displayed....

Answer (score 1):

As default, WebLogic Server uses the port 7001. You can take a look at the `${DOMAIN_HOME}/config/config/xml` file and see what is your server port.